# How to generate a random string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, random, passwords

I'm currently generating an 8-character pseudo-random uppercase string for "A" .. "Z":

```
value = ""; 8.times{value  << (65 + rand(25)).chr}
```

but it doesn't look clean, and it can't be passed as an argument since it isn't a single statement.  To get a mixed-case string "a" .. "z" plus "A" .. "Z", I changed it to:

```
value = ""; 8.times{value << ((rand(2)==1?65:97) + rand(25)).chr}
```

but it looks like trash.

Does anyone have a better method?

Comment: I don't understand why you care that "since it isn't a single statement it can't be passed as an argument". Why not just make it a utility or helper method?

Comment: Suppose there is a method to reset a user's password and it has an argument for the new password. I would like to pass in a random string, in the above code I need a tmp variable, whereas in the single statement examples bellow I can do the whole thing as a one liner. Sure a utility method could be nice in the long run, esp if I'm needing similar here and there, but sometimes you just want it in place, one time, done.

Comment: No, you don't have to use a temporary variable. Try this: `reset_user_password!(random_string)` where `def random_string; SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(20) end`

Comment: 8 letters is a shamefully weak password. Given the md5sum a modern PC could recover the password in [30 seconds](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html). How about something longer [`securerandom.urlsafe_base64`](http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/securerandom/1.9.2/SecureRandom#urlsafe_base64-class_method)

Comment: well, put a webdesigner infront of VIM and ask him to save and exit; Jokes apart. `require 'securerandom'; SecureRandom.hex(15)` should work fine

Answer (score 1042, accepted):

```
(0...8).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
```

I spend too much time golfing.

```
(0...50).map { ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join
```

And a last one that's even more confusing, but more flexible and wastes fewer cycles:

```
o = [('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z')].map(&:to_a).flatten
string = (0...50).map { o[rand(o.length)] }.join
```

If you want to generate some random text then use the following:

```
50.times.map { (0...(rand(10))).map { ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join }.join(" ")
```

this code generates 50 random word string with words length less than 10 characters and then join with space

Comment: 34 characters and blazing fast: `('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0,8].join`. Note you'll need Ruby >=1.9 to `shuffle`.

Comment: first example should be rand(26) otherwise you never get the letter 'Z'

Comment: Leveraging existing libraries is preferable unless you have a driver to roll your own. See `SecureRandom` as one example, in the other answers.

Comment: @faraz your method isn't functionally the same, it's not random with replacement.

Comment: Touche @michaeltwofish. Here's the shortest and most performant one-liner I could muster: `[].fill(0,l){rand(65..90).chr}.join` (35 chars). `fill` is faster than `map`, but for real performance, drop the golf and prebuild the array with a _proper_ use of `sample`: `chars=["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];[].fill(0,l){chars.sample}.join` That not even significantly faster for 8 characters. With 8 characters, no worries. Anything flies. ;)  See my [full benchmarks](http://goo.gl/cOu9G) for details.

Comment: `[*('a'..'z'),*('0'..'9')].shuffle[0,8].join` to generate a random string with both letters and numbers.

Comment: `rand` is deterministic and predictable. Don't use this for generating passwords! Use one of the `SecureRandom` solutions instead.

Comment: the last example should read

`(0...50).map { [('a'..'z'),('A'..'Z')].flat_map(&:to_a).sample }.join`

you definitely *have not* spent _too_ much time golfing xD

Comment: further reduced from Dennis's answer `(0..50).map { [*'a'..'z',*'A'..'Z'].sample }.join`

Comment: Always use existing solutions like SecureRandom in favor of homegrown "random" solutions. Seriously, they are there for a reason.

Comment: @TanelSuurhans As the OP of this answer I agree with all the sentiments regarding "use proven tested tools". Just at the time of this answer, such tools were not core yet, and author appeared to have golfing as an objective.  Understanding how your language works is just as important as using tools written in the language.

Comment: The solutions with `shuffle` wouldn't be that awesome, as they'd generate strings with one occurrence of a character ( so string such as "gbalgqut" would be impossible - double "g" )

Comment: If golf is the objective, `('a'..'z')` is identical to `(?a..?z)`; two characters saved.

Answer (score 867):

Why not use SecureRandom?

```
require 'securerandom'
random_string = SecureRandom.hex

# outputs: 5b5cd0da3121fc53b4bc84d0c8af2e81 (i.e. 32 chars of 0..9, a..f)
```

SecureRandom also has methods for:

- base64
- random_bytes
- random_number

see: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html

Comment: This generates strings that aren't safe for passing as get variables for websites - for example, you can get string=+fGH1 (+ is read as a space), and string=fyhi/ (the slash is used for navigation)

Comment: base64 would, but not hex like in his example

Comment: By the way, it's part of the stdlib in 1.9 and recent 1.8 versions, so one can just `require 'securerandom'` to get this neat `SecureRandom` helper :)

Comment: @JeffDickey no, thats wrong. `SecureRandom.base64 => "7p0lfNClJwolM9BJcgG5lQ=="` as you see, there are `=` in it. Method hex only returns `0-9a-f`

Comment: BTW SecureRandom was removed from ActiveSupport in version 3.2. From the changelog: "Removed ActiveSupport::SecureRandom in favor of SecureRandom from the standard library".

Comment: `SecureRandom.random_number(36**12).to_s(36).rjust(12, "0")` will generate a string with 0-9a-z (36 characters) that is ALWAYS 12 characters long.  Change 12 to whatever length you want.  Unfortunately no way to just get A-Z using `Integer#to_s`.

Comment: @stringo0 that is wrong.  If you wanted to pass `+fGH1` through a URL, you just need to URL-encode it like you would ANY value that's going through a URL:  `%2BfGH1`

Comment: To generate a string containing only 5 alpha characters you could do this `SecureRandom.hex.gsub(/\d/, "")[0..4]`

Comment: Hi, I like SecureRandom, but how do I get a string of 6 numbers, each digit with range 0-9. And I would like it in a way that it's easy to stub in my Rails controller spec.

Comment: I tried 'SecureRandom.random_number(9**6)' but it sometimes returns 5 numbers but it sometimes returns 6 numbers.

Comment: What are the chances of getting a duplicate?

Comment: @dcangulo hello from the future!  The chances are low enough that you generally don't need to worry about it with something like `SecureRandom.hex`, but it's not impossible. If you're using this to generate unique IDs, use `SecureRandom.uuid`.

Comment: @JakeRobb Err, `SecureRandom.uuid` is exactly as likely to generate duplicates as `SecureRandom.hex`. They are two different encodings for 128 random bits.

Comment: Right you are, thanks for the callout! I was thinking of Type 1 UUIDs, but this method generates a Type 4.

Answer (score 272):

I use this for generating random URL friendly strings with a length between 1 and  `string_length` characters:

```
string_length = 8
rand(36**string_length).to_s(36)
```

It generates random strings of lowercase a-z and 0-9. It's not very customizable but it's short and clean.

Comment: +1 for the shortest version (that doesn't call external binaries ^^).  If the random string isn't public facing, I sometimes even just use `rand.to_s`; ugly, but works.

Comment: This is a great solution (and fast, too), but it will occasionally produce a string *under* `length` length, roughly once in ~40

Comment: @Brian E this would guarantee the digits you want: `(36**(length-1) + rand(36**length)).to_s(36)`.  36**(length-1) converted to base 36 is 10**(length-1), which is the smallest value that has the digit length you want.

Comment: @EricHu You're solution also produce tokens longer than `length`.

Comment: Here is the version always producing tokens of the desired length: `(36**(length-1) + rand(36**length - 36**(length-1))).to_s(36)`

Comment: Yep, +1 for brevity and lack of dependencies.

Comment: @BigBourin Your solution doesnt always produce tokens of desired length

Comment: This spits out an error for me in Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1.1: `NameError: undefined local variable or method `length' for main:Object`

Comment: This will give you an exact length: `Random.new.rand( 36**(length-1) ... 36**length ).to_s( 36 )`

Comment: If you need speed and exact length, you can also use this, which runs about 20x faster than the one in my last comment: `( rand * (36**length - 36**(length-1) ) + 36**(length-1) ).floor.to_s( 36 )`. It's not as readable though, so I would put it in a function. Probably the simplest would be to generate something that is guaranteed to be to long, and then truncate it.

Comment: I'm using this to generate 6 char tokens in a very simple way: `rand(36**11).to_s(36).upcase[0,6]` i.e. just make the original string safely long enough and then take any N chars from it

Comment: @JanKlimo That's just wrong though. `rand(36**11).to_s(36)` may return a string with only 1 character.  There are ways of doing this that are provably correct and will work 100% of the time, and there is your way, which may randomly produce fewer digits than is required. Don't do that. Don't write code that is probabilistically correct, when *guaranteed* correct is so trivial.

Answer (score 177):

This solution generates a string of easily readable characters for activation codes; I didn't want people confusing 8 with B, 1 with I, 0 with O, L with 1, etc.

```
# Generates a random string from a set of easily readable characters
def generate_activation_code(size = 6)
  charset = %w{ 2 3 4 6 7 9 A C D E F G H J K M N P Q R T V W X Y Z}
  (0...size).map{ charset.to_a[rand(charset.size)] }.join
end
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use `charset.sample` instead of `charset.to_a[rand(charset.size)`?

Comment: @Tom, if you are using Ruby 1.9 or Rails then yes.  Plain 1.8.7 then no.

Comment: Is 'U' ambiguous or is that a typo?

Comment: @gtd - Yep. U and V are ambigvovs.

Comment: @colinm V's in there though.

Comment: To be secure you would also want to use `SecureRandom.random_number(charset.size)` instead of `rand(charset.size)`

Comment: I was just trying to improve on this, by adding lower case and/or some special characters (shift+num), and got the following lists: `%w{ A C D E F G H J K L M N P Q R T W X Y Z 2 3 4 6 7 9 ! @ # $ % ^ & * +}` and `%w{ A D E F G H J L N Q R T Y a d e f h n r y 2 3 4 7 ! @ # $ % ^ & * }` (first list doesn't include lower case, but it's longer) Kinda interesting how that worked out.

Answer (score 140):

Since Ruby 2.5, it's really easy with `SecureRandom.alphanumeric`:

```
len = 8
SecureRandom.alphanumeric(len)
=> "larHSsgL"
```

It generates random strings containing A-Z, a-z and 0-9 and therefore should be applicable in most use-cases. And they are generated randomly secure, which might be a benefit, too.

---

This is a benchmark to compare it with the solution having the most upvotes:

```
require 'benchmark'
require 'securerandom'

len = 10
n = 100_000

Benchmark.bm(12) do |x|
  x.report('SecureRandom') { n.times { SecureRandom.alphanumeric(len) } }
  x.report('rand') do
    o = [('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z'), (0..9)].map(&:to_a).flatten
    n.times { (0...len).map { o[rand(o.length)] }.join }
  end
end
```

---

```
                   user     system      total        real
SecureRandom   0.429442   0.002746   0.432188 (  0.432705)
rand           0.306650   0.000716   0.307366 (  0.307745)
```

So the `rand` solution only takes about 3/4 of the time of `SecureRandom`. That might matter if you generate a lot of strings, but if you just create some random string from time to time I'd always go with the more secure implementation since it is also easier to call and more explicit.

Comment: Now we need a similar solution for 0-z (without the uppercase characters). SecureRandom doesn't seem to provide that out of the box.

Answer (score 136):

Others have mentioned something similar, but this uses the  URL safe function.

```
require 'securerandom'
p SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(5) #=> "UtM7aa8"
p SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 #=> "UZLdOkzop70Ddx-IJR0ABg"
p SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, true) #=> "i0XQ-7gglIsHGV2_BNPrdQ=="
```

The result may contain A-Z, a-z, 0-9, “-” and “_”. “=” is also used if padding is true.

Answer (score 55):

```
[*('A'..'Z')].sample(8).join
```

Generate a random 8 letter string (e.g. NVAYXHGR)

```
([*('A'..'Z'),*('0'..'9')]-%w(0 1 I O)).sample(8).join
```

Generate a random 8 character string (e.g. 3PH4SWF2), excludes 0/1/I/O. Ruby 1.9

Comment: Only problem is each character in the result is unique. Limits the possible values.

Comment: If this [feature request](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/822646) goes through, Ruby 1.9.x may end up with #sample for sampling without replacment and #choice for sampling with replacement.

Comment: This is an error, i think you need ... `[*("A".."Z")]'` ; ((not single qoutes))

Comment: can you tell me how i can `stub` this for `rspec` to pass.

Answer (score 31):

I can't remember where I found this, but it seems like the best and the least process intensive to me:

```
def random_string(length=10)
  chars = 'abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'
  password = ''
  length.times { password << chars[rand(chars.size)] }
  password
end
```

Comment: Perhaps you found it here? http://travisonrails.com/2007/06/07/generate-random-text-with-ruby

Comment: Isn't there a 0 and 1 missing from this?

Comment: Looks like that could be where I found it.

Comment: And ya, it does look like 0 and 1 are missing.

Comment: The `0` and `1` and `O` and `I` were intentionally missing because those characters are ambiguous. If this sort of code is being used to generate a set of characters that a user needs to copy, it's best to exclude characters that may be difficult to distinguish out of context.

Answer (score 29):

```
require 'securerandom'
SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(9)
```

Comment: old skool (and uglier) alternative: `Random.new.bytes(9)`

Comment: btw, urlsafe_base64 returns a string about 4/3 the length indicated. To get a string exactly n chars long, try `n=9 ; SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(n)[0..n-1]`

Answer (score 26):

If you want a string of specified length, use:

```
require 'securerandom'
randomstring = SecureRandom.hex(n)
```

It will generate a random string of length `2n` containing `0-9` and `a-f`

Comment: It doesn't generate a string of length `n`, it actually generates a string that's 4/3 of `n`.

Comment: @OmarAli you're wrong. As per Ruby documentation in case of `.hex` it's 2n. Documentation: SecureRandom.hex generates a random hexadecimal string. The argument _n_ specifies the length, in bytes, of the random number to be generated. The length of the resulting hexadecimal string is twice of _n_.

Answer (score 15):

`Array.new(n){[*"0".."9"].sample}.join`,
where `n=8` in your case.

Generalized: `Array.new(n){[*"A".."Z", *"0".."9"].sample}.join`, etc.

From: "[Generate pseudo random string A-Z, 0-9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076011/rails-generate-pseudo-random-string-a-z-0-9/26076063#26076063)".

Answer (score 11):

```
require 'sha1'
srand
seed = "--#{rand(10000)}--#{Time.now}--"
Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(seed)[0,8]
```

Comment: Interesting, but quite a bit more computationally expensive

Comment: Also no capacity for limited scope of characters.

Comment: Keep in mind that a hex digest returns only 0-9 and a-f characters.

Answer (score 11):

Ruby 1.9+:

```
ALPHABET = ('a'..'z').to_a
#=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]

10.times.map { ALPHABET.sample }.join
#=> "stkbssowre"

# or

10.times.inject('') { |s| s + ALPHABET.sample }
#=> "fdgvacnxhc"
```

Comment: The `map` solution is really nice!

Comment: You can ask `#sample` for how many elements you want. E.g. `ALPHABET.sample(10).join`... https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sample

Comment: That is actually wrong. `sample(10)` gives you 10 unique samples. But you want to allow them to repeat. 

But I would use `Array.new(10).map` for performance

Comment: I wanted alphanumeric with both lower and upper cases. I've also switched to use `Array.new` and its block syntax.

`Array.new(20) { [*'0'..'9', *'a'..'z', *'A'..'Z'].sample }.join`

Answer (score 11):

Here is one line simple code for random string with length 8:

```
 random_string = ('0'..'z').to_a.shuffle.first(8).join
```

You can also use it for random password having length 8:

```
random_password = ('0'..'z').to_a.shuffle.first(8).join
```

Comment: You should not use this to generate yourself a password, as this method will never repeat a character. Therefore you're only using `P(36, 8) / 36^8 = 0.4` of the possible character space for 8 characters (~2x easier to brute force) or `P(36, 25) / 36^25 = 0.00001` of the possible character space for 25 characters (~100,000x easier to brute force).

Answer (score 8):

Another method I like to use:

```
 rand(2**256).to_s(36)[0..7]
```

Add `ljust` if you are really paranoid about the correct string length:

```
 rand(2**256).to_s(36).ljust(8,'a')[0..7]
```

Comment: Even better to grab the least significant part of the random number by using the right hand side of the string:
rand(2**64).to_s(36)[-10,10]

Answer (score 8):

Be aware: `rand` is predictable for an attacker and therefore probably insecure. You should definitely use SecureRandom if this is for generating passwords. I use something like this:

```
length = 10
characters = ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a + ('0'..'9').to_a

password = SecureRandom.random_bytes(length).each_char.map do |char|
  characters[(char.ord % characters.length)]
end.join
```

Comment: This is probably the "most" secure solution. SecureRandom attempts to use underlying security APIs provided by the operating system. If you have OpenSSL it will use that, if you're on Windows it will go the best option there.

I especially like this solution because it allows you to specify a set of characters for use. Though it won't work if your character set is longer than the maximum value of a byte: 255.

I recommend viewing the source code for SecureRandom in the doc: 
http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-random_bytes

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a nice balance of conciseness, clarity and ease of modification.

```
characters = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a
# Prior to 1.9, use .choice, not .sample
(0..8).map{characters.sample}.join
```

#### Easily modified

For example, including digits:

```
characters = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + (0..9).to_a
```

Uppercase hexadecimal:

```
characters = ('A'..'F').to_a + (0..9).to_a
```

For a truly impressive array of characters:

```
characters = (32..126).to_a.pack('U*').chars.to_a
```

Comment: i would recommend this to just use capital letters + numbers, also remove the "confusing" ones
        charset = (1..9).to_a.concat(('A'..'Z').to_a).reject{ |a| [0, 1, 'O', 'I'].include?(a) }
        (0...size).map{ charset[rand(charset.size)] }.join

Answer (score 7):

```
SecureRandom.base64(15).tr('+/=lIO0', 'pqrsxyz')
```

Something from Devise

Comment: Why is it replacing string characters using `.tr('+/=lIO0', 'pqrsxyz')`?

Comment: The special characters because they are not URL safe. And l/I or O/0 because they are very easy confused if you use the technique to generate readable user passwords.

Comment: That function has a bit of bias towards certain characters. Also for other lengths (e.g. 16), the last character will not be random. Here's a way to avoid that.

    SecureRandom.base64(64).tr('+/=lIO01', '')[0,16]

Answer (score 7):

Here is one simple code for random password with length 8:

```
rand_password=('0'..'z').to_a.shuffle.first(8).join
```

Answer (score 5):

Just adding my cents here...

```
def random_string(length = 8)
  rand(32**length).to_s(32)
end
```

Comment: NB: this doesn't always return a string exactly +length+ long - it may be shorter. It depends on the the number returned by `rand`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`String#random`](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/blob/126a619fd766bc45588cac18d09c4f1927538e33/lib/core/facets/string/random.rb) from the Facets of Ruby Gem `facets`.

It basically does this:

```
class String
  def self.random(len=32, character_set = ["A".."Z", "a".."z", "0".."9"])
    characters = character_set.map { |i| i.to_a }.flatten
    characters_len = characters.length
    (0...len).map{ characters[rand(characters_len)] }.join
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I was doing something like this recently to generate an 8 byte random string from 62 characters.  The characters were 0-9,a-z,A-Z.  I had an array of them as was looping 8 times and picking a random value out of the array.  This was inside a Rails app.

```
str = ''
8.times {|i| str << ARRAY_OF_POSSIBLE_VALUES[rand(SIZE_OF_ARRAY_OF_POSSIBLE_VALUES)] }
```

The weird thing is that I got good number of duplicates.  Now randomly this should pretty much never happen.  62^8 is huge, but out of 1200 or so codes in the db i had a good number of duplicates.  I noticed them happening on hour boundaries of each other. In other words I might see a duple at 12:12:23 and 2:12:22 or something like that...not sure if time is the issue or not.

This code was in the before create of an ActiveRecord object.   Before the record was created this code would run and generate the 'unique' code.  Entries in the DB were always produced reliably, but the code (`str` in the above line) was being duplicated much too often.

I created a script to run through 100000 iterations of this above line with small delay so it would take 3-4 hours hoping to see some kind of repeat pattern on an hourly basis, but saw nothing.  I have no idea why this was happening in my Rails app.

Answer (score 4):

Given:

```
chars = [*('a'..'z'),*('0'..'9')].flatten
```

Single expression, can be passed as an argument, allows duplicate characters:

```
Array.new(len) { chars.sample }.join
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution needs external dependency, but seems prettier than another.

1. Install gem [faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker)
2. `Faker::Lorem.characters(10) # => "ang9cbhoa8"`

Comment: Passing number with the 1st argument of characters is deprecated. Use keyword argument like `characters(number: ...)` instead.



`Faker::Lorem.characters(number: 10) # => "ang9cbhoa8"`

Answer (score 3):

With this method you can pass in an abitrary length. It's set as a default as 6.

```
def generate_random_string(length=6)
  string = ""
  chars = ("A".."Z").to_a
  length.times do
    string << chars[rand(chars.length-1)]
  end
  string
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I like Radar's answer best, so far, I think. I'd tweak a bit like this:

```
CHARS = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a
def rand_string(length=8)
  s=''
  length.times{ s << CHARS[rand(CHARS.length)] }
  s
end
```

Comment: Why not use `(CHARS*length).sample(length).join`?

Comment: @niels This suggestion would generate a *weighted* string, in favour of non-repeated characters. For example, if `CHARS=['a','b']` then your method would generate `"aa"` or `"bb"` only 33% of the time, but `"ab"` or `"ba"` 67% of the time. Maybe that's not a problem, but it's worth bearing in mind!

Comment: good point, @TomLord, I think I didn't actually realise that when I posted that suggestion (although I must admit I don't remember posting that at all :D)

Answer (score 3):

2 solutions for a random string consisting of 3 ranges:

```
(('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + (0..9).to_a).sample(8).join

([*(48..57),*(65..90),*(97..122)]).sample(8).collect(&:chr)*""
```

#### One Character from each Range.

And if you need at least one character from each range, such as creating a random password that has one uppercase, one lowercase letter and one digit, you can do something like this:

```
( ('a'..'z').to_a.sample(8) + ('A'..'Z').to_a.sample(8) + (0..9).to_a.sample(8) ).shuffle.join 
#=> "Kc5zOGtM0H796QgPp8u2Sxo1"
```

Comment: And if you want to enforce a certain number of each range, you could do something like this: `( ('a'..'z').to_a.sample(8) + ('A'..'Z').to_a.sample(8) + (0..9).to_a.sample(8) + [ "%", "!", "*" ].sample(8) ).shuffle.join #=> "Kc5zOGtM0*H796QgPp%!8u2Sxo1"`

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents:

```
  def token(length=16)
    chars = [*('A'..'Z'), *('a'..'z'), *(0..9)]
    (0..length).map {chars.sample}.join
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

My favorite is `(:A..:Z).to_a.shuffle[0,8].join`.  Note that shuffle requires Ruby > 1.9.

Answer (score 3):

Another trick that works with Ruby 1.8+ and is fast is:

```
>> require "openssl"
>> OpenSSL::Random.random_bytes(20).unpack('H*').join
=> "2f3ff53dd712ba2303a573d9f9a8c1dbc1942d28"
```

It get's you random hex string. Similar way you should be able to generate base64 string ('M*').

Answer (score 2):

We've been using this on our code:

```
class String

  def self.random(length=10)
    ('a'..'z').sort_by {rand}[0,length].join
  end

end
```

The maximum length supported is 25 (we're only using it with the default anyway, so hasn't been a problem).

Someone mentioned that 'a'..'z' is suboptimal if you want to completely avoid generating offensive words. One of the ideas we had was removing vowels, but you still end up with WTFBBQ etc.

Comment: Your approach can't return repeating characters (e.g, uuunMoBldj)... Is this what's wanted?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that technically isn't really a random string anymore, good find webmat.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another method:

- It uses the secure random number generator instead of rand()
- Can be used in URLs and file names
- Contains uppercase, lowercase characters and numbers
- Has an option not to include ambiguous characters I0l01

Needs `require "securerandom"`

```
def secure_random_string(length = 32, non_ambiguous = false)
  characters = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('0'..'9').to_a

  %w{I O l 0 1}.each{ |ambiguous_character| 
    characters.delete ambiguous_character 
  } if non_ambiguous

  (0...length).map{
    characters[ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.random_number(characters.size)]
  }.join
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
''.tap {|v| 4.times { v << ('a'..'z').to_a.sample} }
```

Answer (score 1):

try this out

```
def rand_name(len=9)
  ary = [('0'..'9').to_a, ('a'..'z').to_a, ('A'..'Z').to_a]
  name = ''

  len.times do
    name << ary.choice.choice
  end
  name
end
```

I love the answers of the thread, have been very helpful, indeed!, but if I may say, none of them satisfies my ayes, maybe is the rand() method. it's just doesn't seems right to me, since we've got the Array#choice method for that matter.

Comment: `ar = [('0'..'9').to_a, ('a'..'z').to_a, ('A'..'Z').to_a].flatten; 10.times.map { ar.choice }.join`

Answer (score 1):

This is based on a few other answers, but it adds a bit more complexity:

```
def random_password
  specials = ((32..47).to_a + (58..64).to_a + (91..96).to_a + (123..126).to_a).pack('U*').chars.to_a
  numbers  = (0..9).to_a
  alpha    = ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a
  %w{i I l L 1 O o 0}.each{ |ambiguous_character| 
    alpha.delete ambiguous_character 
  }
  characters = (alpha + specials + numbers)
  password = Random.new.rand(8..18).times.map{characters.sample}
  password << specials.sample unless password.join =~ Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(specials.join))
  password << numbers.sample  unless password.join =~ Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(numbers.join))
  password.shuffle.join
end
```

Essentially it ensures a password that is 8 - 20 characters in length, and which contains at least one number and one special character.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a UNIX and you still must use Ruby 1.8 (no SecureRandom) without Rails, you can also use this:

```
random_string = `openssl rand -base64 24`
```

Note this spawns new shell, this is very slow and it can only be recommended for scripts.

Answer (score 1):

For devise secure_validatable you can use this

```rb
(0...8).map { ([65, 97].sample + rand(26)).chr }.push(rand(99)).join
```

Comment: To generate a random password using uppercase, lowercase, numbers, and special characters, I used something like:

`random_ascii_character = -> { (33..126).to_a.sample.chr };
8.times.map { random_ascii_character.call }.shuffle.join`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a improve of @Travis R answer:

```
 def random_string(length=5)
    chars = 'abdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyzABDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    numbers = '0123456789'
    random_s = ''
    (length/2).times { random_s << numbers[rand(numbers.size)] }
    (length - random_s.length).times { random_s << chars[rand(chars.size)] }
    random_s.split('').shuffle.join
  end
```

At @Travis R answer chars and numbers were together, so sometimes `random_string` could return only numbers or only characters. With this improve at least half of `random_string` will be characters and the rest are numbers. Just in case if you need a random string with numbers and characters

Answer (score 0):

To make your first into one statement:

```
(0...8).collect { |n| value  << (65 + rand(25)).chr }.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty string or a pre-fix if require:

```
myStr = "OID-"
```

Use this code to populate the string with random numbers:

```
begin; n = ((rand * 43) + 47).ceil; myStr << n.chr if !(58..64).include?(n); end while(myStr.length < 12)
```

Notes:

```
(rand * 43) + 47).ceil
```

It will generate random numbers from 48-91 (0,1,2..Y,Z)

```
!(58..64).include?(n)
```

It is used to skip special characters (as I am not interested to include them)

```
while(myStr.length < 12)
```

It will generate total 12 characters long string including prefix.

Sample Output:

```
"OID-XZ2J32XM"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that is flexible and allows dups:

```
class String
  # generate a random string of length n using current string as the source of characters
  def random(n)
    return "" if n <= 0
    (chars * (n / length + 1)).shuffle[0..n-1].join  
  end
end
```

Example:

```
"ATCG".random(8) => "CGTGAAGA"
```

You can also allow a certain character to appear more frequently:

```
"AAAAATCG".random(10) => "CTGAAAAAGC"
```

Explanation:
The method above takes the chars of a given string and generates a big enough array. It then shuffles it, takes the first n items, then joins them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.new(8).inject(""){|r|r<<('0'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0]}  # 57
(1..8).inject(""){|r|r<<('0'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0]}        # 51
e="";8.times{e<<('0'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0]};e              # 45
(1..8).map{('0'..'z').to_a.shuffle[0]}.join                # 43
(1..8).map{rand(49..122).chr}.join                         # 34
```

Answer (score 0):

```
10.times do 
  alphabet = ('a'..'z').to_a
  string += alpha[rand(alpha.length)]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a='';8.times{a<<[*'a'..'z'].sample};p a
```

or

```
8.times.collect{[*'a'..'z'].sample}.join
```

Answer (score -1):

This is almost as ugly but perhaps as step in right direction?

```
 (1..8).map{|i| ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)]}.join
```

Comment: :) I actually love the fastest gun in a perverse way

Answer (score -1):

In ruby 1.9 one can use Array's choice method which returns random element from array

Comment: Thanks for the heads up - however, http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_9_1_0/NEWS seems to indicate that Array#sample is to be used in 1.9.1, not Array#choose / choice