# How do I generate a list of n unique random numbers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, random

This is what I have so far:

```
myArray.map!{ rand(max) }
```

Obviously, however, sometimes the numbers in the list are not unique. How can I make sure my list only contains unique numbers without having to create a bigger list from which I then just pick the n unique numbers?

**Edit:**
I'd really like to see this done w/o loop - if at all possible.

Comment: FYI, my answer shows a pattern that works without a loop

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This uses Set:

```
require 'set'

def rand_n(n, max)
    randoms = Set.new
    loop do
        randoms << rand(max)
        return randoms.to_a if randoms.size >= n
    end
end
```

Comment: Any way to do this w/o looping? Any way to do it with a map?

Comment: Assuming that Ruby's Set doesn't allow insertion of duplicates, `randoms` will be less random than `rand(max)` since you're simply throwing away numbers that "you don't like".

Comment: @Allen that is not correct.  The algorithm isn't throwing away numbers "you don't like".  An example of that would be throwing away a number because it is greater than or less than a certain value.  What it is doing is skipping a number if it has already been included in the set, which is a requirement of the use case.  That does not make the set of numbers less random.  It stops when it has enough numbers.

Comment: @Tony you're correct that I was not correct.  Not sure what I was smoking in 2014.

Answer (score 66):

```
(0..50).to_a.sort{ rand() - 0.5 }[0..x]
```

`(0..50).to_a` can be replaced with any array. 
0 is "minvalue", 50 is "max value" 
x is "how many values i want out"

of course, its impossible for x to be permitted to be greater than max-min :)

In expansion of how this works

```
(0..5).to_a  ==> [0,1,2,3,4,5]
[0,1,2,3,4,5].sort{ -1 }  ==>  [0, 1, 2, 4, 3, 5]  # constant
[0,1,2,3,4,5].sort{  1 }  ==>  [5, 3, 0, 4, 2, 1]  # constant
[0,1,2,3,4,5].sort{ rand() - 0.5 }   ==>  [1, 5, 0, 3, 4, 2 ]  # random
[1, 5, 0, 3, 4, 2 ][ 0..2 ]   ==>  [1, 5, 0 ]
```

#### Footnotes:

It is worth mentioning that at the time this question was originally answered, September 2008, that [`Array#shuffle`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-shuffle) was either not available or not already known to me, hence the approximation in [`Array#sort`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-sort)

And there's a barrage of suggested edits to this as a result.

So:

```
.sort{ rand() - 0.5 }
```

Can be better, and shorter expressed on modern ruby implementations using

```
.shuffle
```

Additionally,

```
[0..x]
```

Can be more obviously written with [`Array#take`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-take) as:

```
.take(x)
```

Thus, the easiest way to produce a sequence of random numbers on a modern ruby is:

```
(0..50).to_a.shuffle.take(x)
```

Comment: is not [0,1,2,3,4,5].shuffle easier ?

Comment: hehehe :) I had to say @Federico. Brilliant :))

Comment: Look at the date @Federico , ruby didn't have such a method at the start of 2008 with 1.8.6 http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.6/Array.html , was added in 1.8.7 as far as I can tell. http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/tags/v1_8_7/ChangeLog

Comment: ( 1.8.7 was probably out at that time, but I probably hadn't updated to it yet, or learned of the addition of `.shuffle` )

Comment: (0..50).to_a.shuffle.take(x)   brilliant !!

Comment: If you have a dynamic upper limit, this method might generate extremely large arrays. I think it would be better to use 

`n.times.map { rand(lower_limit..upper_limit) }`

Comment: @DanielRichter and that approach of course gives no guarantees of uniqueness.

Answer (score 24):

Ruby 1.9 offers the Array#sample method which returns an element, or elements randomly selected from an Array. The results of #sample won't include the same Array element twice.

```
(1..999).to_a.sample 5 # => [389, 30, 326, 946, 746]
```

When compared to the `to_a.sort_by` approach, the `sample` method appears to be significantly faster. In a simple scenario I compared `sort_by` to `sample`, and got the following results.

```
require 'benchmark'
range = 0...1000000
how_many = 5

Benchmark.realtime do
  range.to_a.sample(how_many)
end
=> 0.081083

Benchmark.realtime do
  (range).sort_by{rand}[0...how_many]
end
=> 2.907445
```

Comment: Any idea of the timing compared to what glenn mcdonald reports?

Answer (score 22):

Just to give you an idea about speed, I ran four versions of this:

1. Using Sets, like Ryan's suggestion.
2. Using an Array slightly larger than necessary, then doing uniq! at the end.
3. Using a Hash, like Kyle suggested.
4. Creating an Array of the required size, then sorting it randomly, like Kent's suggestion (but without the extraneous "- 0.5", which does nothing).

They're all fast at small scales, so I had them each create a list of 1,000,000 numbers. Here are the times, in seconds:

1. Sets: 628
2. Array + uniq: 629
3. Hash: 645
4. fixed Array + sort: 8

And no, that last one is not a typo. So if you care about speed, and it's OK for the numbers to be integers from 0 to whatever, then my exact code was:

```
a = (0...1000000).sort_by{rand}
```

Comment: A linear feedback shift register should complete in under a second.

Comment: ` extraneous "- 0.5", which does nothing` 

Did you try it?

Without - 0.5 , rand() always returns > 0, and when > 0, a is always smaller than b, and then instead of shuffling, ... you simply get returned the list in the order the underlying algorithm compared them.

Which in some cases, returns the list in order given.

`(0..10).to­_a.sort{ Rando­m.rand() }` on http://tryruby.org/levels/1/challenges/0  gives me input == output. So you **REALLY DO** need that - 0.5, or the **random itself does nothing**

Comment: Also, you're really responding to tiny asides in a SO thread six years after the fact?!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible to do this without a loop and without keeping track of which numbers have been chosen.   It's called a Linear Feedback Shift Register:  [Create Random Number Sequence with No Repeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693880/create-random-number-sequence-with-no-repeats)

Answer (score 4):

```
[*1..99].sample(4) #=> [64, 99, 29, 49]
```

According to `Array#sample` docs,

> The elements are chosen by using random and **unique** indices

If you need `SecureRandom` (which uses computer noise instead of pseudorandom numbers):

```
require 'securerandom'

[*1..99].sample(4, random: SecureRandom) #=> [2, 75, 95, 37]
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a play on this? Unique random numbers without needing to use Set or Hash.

```
x = 0
(1..100).map{|iter| x += rand(100)}.shuffle
```

Comment: I somehow feel that these numbers will be significantly less random than by picking 100 unique ones from the range of 0 to 10000.

Comment: yerp, it needs to be improved, the higher the number the lower the odds you will get it. But surely there is a way of getting something along these lines to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash to track the random numbers you've used so far:

```
seen = {}
max = 100
(1..10).map { |n|
  x = rand(max)
  while (seen[x]) 
    x = rand(max)
  end
  x
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than add the items to a list/array, add them to a Set.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a finite list of possible random numbers (i.e. 1 to 100), then Kent's solution is good.

Otherwise there is no other good way to do it without looping. The problem is you MUST do a loop if you get a duplicate. My solution should be efficient and the looping should not be too much more than the size of your array (i.e. if you want 20 unique random numbers, it might take 25 iterations on average.) Though the number of iterations gets worse the more numbers you need and the smaller max is. Here is my above code modified to show how many iterations are needed for the given input:

```
require 'set'

def rand_n(n, max)
    randoms = Set.new
    i = 0
    loop do
        randoms << rand(max)
        break if randoms.size > n
        i += 1
    end
    puts "Took #{i} iterations for #{n} random numbers to a max of #{max}"
    return randoms.to_a
end
```

I could write this code to LOOK more like Array.map if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on Kent Fredric's solution above, this is what I ended up using:

```
def n_unique_rand(number_to_generate, rand_upper_limit)
  return (0..rand_upper_limit - 1).sort_by{rand}[0..number_to_generate - 1]
end
```

Thanks Kent.

Answer (score 1):

No loops with this method

```
Array.new(size) { rand(max) }

require 'benchmark'
max = 1000000
size = 5
Benchmark.realtime do
  Array.new(size) { rand(max) }
end

=> 1.9114e-05
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution:

Suppose you want these random numbers to be between `r_min` and `r_max`. For each element in your list, generate a random number `r`, and make `list[i]=list[i-1]+r`. This would give you random numbers which are monotonically increasing, guaranteeing uniqueness provided that

- `r+list[i-1]` does not over flow
- `r` > 0

For the first element, you would use `r_min` instead of `list[i-1]`. Once you are done, you can shuffle the list so the elements are not so obviously in order.

The only problem with this method is when you go over `r_max` and still have more elements to generate. In this case, you can reset `r_min` and `r_max` to 2 adjacent element you have already computed, and simply repeat the process. This effectively runs the same algorithm over an interval where there are no numbers already used. You can keep doing this until you have the list populated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as it is nice to know in advance the maxium value, you can do this way:

```
class NoLoopRand
  def initialize(max)
    @deck = (0..max).to_a
  end

  def getrnd
    return @deck.delete_at(rand(@deck.length - 1))
  end
end
```

and you can obtain random data in this way:

```
aRndNum = NoLoopRand.new(10)
puts aRndNum.getrnd
```

you'll obtain `nil` when all the values will be exausted from the deck.

Answer (score 0):

### Method 1

Using Kent's approach, it is possible to generate an array of arbitrary length keeping all values in a limited range:

```
# Generates a random array of length n.
#
# @param n     length of the desired array
# @param lower minimum number in the array
# @param upper maximum number in the array
def ary_rand(n, lower, upper)
    values_set = (lower..upper).to_a
    repetition = n/(upper-lower+1) + 1
    (values_set*repetition).sample n
end
```

### Method 2

Another, possibly **more efficient**, method modified from same Kent's [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/88341/471214):

```
def ary_rand2(n, lower, upper)
    v = (lower..upper).to_a
    (0...n).map{ v[rand(v.length)] }
end
```

### Output

```
puts (ary_rand 5, 0, 9).to_s # [0, 8, 2, 5, 6] expected
puts (ary_rand 5, 0, 9).to_s # [7, 8, 2, 4, 3] different result for same params
puts (ary_rand 5, 0, 1).to_s # [0, 0, 1, 0, 1] repeated values from limited range
puts (ary_rand 5, 9, 0).to_s # []              no such range :)
```