# Generate n unique random integers in ruby / rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to generate n unique random numbers between 1 and max

I tried the following code but doesn't work (returns repeated numbers)

```
r = [ ]
n.times { v = rand(max) while r.include? v ; r << v}
```

Whats wrong with it? Thanks

added:

max is thousands

n is 10

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119107/how-do-i-generate-a-list-of-n-unique-random-numbers-in-ruby).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your while r.include logic is the wrong way around. Try this:

```
r = [ ]
while r.length < n 
  v = rand(max)
  r << v unless r.include? v
end
```

Note that this will go into an infinite loop if max < n.

Comment: This will loop infinitely if `rand(max)` keeps drawing the same number.

Answer (score 10):

No, no, don't generate randomly and then check, generate the uniq numbers and then *sort* randomly!

```
(1..max).sort_by{rand}
```

Or, in 1.9:

```
(1..max).to_a.shuffle
```

Comment: ...and then pick the first n numbers. I suppose this method works well if max is not big. In my case max is thousands and n is 10.

Comment: Then `(1..max).to_a.shuffle[0,n]` should work. Much less efficient, but easier to read, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

`Kernel#rand` generates a pseudorandom number. This should cause concern if security is an issue.

In Rails use `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.random_number`

Also both `Kernel#rand` and `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.random_number` may return 0, you say the value must be between 1 and max.

Comment: Thank you Steve, but security is not an issue in this case. However I wonder how can any algorithm generate other random than a pseudo-random number. Do you have more information on this SecureRandom class?

Comment: Use Cosmic Background Radiation lol. Good point, I wasn't clear on that. SecureRandom also generates pseudorandom numbers, but it can use the OpenSSL random number generators or /dev/urandom, both of which are crypotgraphically secure.

Comment: Apparently Kernel#rand also uses /dev/urandom if available, the Ruby docs don't mention this just that it uses a modified Mersenne Twister which caused my alarm. Then again you are also at the mercy of how well /dev/urandom is implemented in the deployment environment's OS. 

ActiveSupport::SecureRandom will use OpenSSL if available.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use hash rather than array, because the complexity to compare a number in Array is array.length while in hash it's 1.   And you can finally transfer hash keys into an array.

```
hash = {}   r = [ ]
while hash.length < n
  a = rand(max)
  if !hash_has_key? (a)
     hash(a) = :ok
  end
end

r = hash.keys
```

if you test n=30000 and max = 500000, the time consumed is very different compared with using array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the exact ruby syntax, but as an algorithm:

```
list = [1 .. 10000];

nums = [];

while (nums.length < needed) {
    nums.push( list.splice(rand() * list.length) )
}
```

should work fairly well, so long as your range isn't too big and won't need to waste time shuffling the entire list