# Generate unique integer in range using Faker gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, faker

This seems like it should be simple but I can't find an answer anywhere!

I'm building a sample_data rake file in Rails to populate my db using the Faker gem. (though I don't think I need that gem for just generating integers)

Some of the fields need to be an integer within a set range but each must be unique.  For instance:

```
10.times do |a|
  a.special_number = rand(1..10)
end
```

works well except for the fact that the numbers aren't unique...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I generate a list of n unique random numbers in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119107/how-do-i-generate-a-list-of-n-unique-random-numbers-in-ruby)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of trying to generate a list of unique random numbers, why don't you generate a range of numbers and shuffle that list?

Comment: Also checkout this similar post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996864/generate-n-unique-random-integers-in-ruby-rails?rq=1

Comment: That probably works just fine..  How would that look in code?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at the second answer `(1..max).sort_by{rand}`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use hash rather than array, because the complexity to compare a number in Array is array.length while in hash it's 1. And you can finally transfer hash keys into an array.

```
hash = {}   r = [ ]
while hash.length < n
  a = rand(max)
  if !hash_has_key? (a)
     hash(a) = :ok
  end
end

r = hash.keys
```

if you test n=30000 and max = 500000, the time consumed is very different compared with using array.