# Select a random number a random number of times but never the same random number twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I generate a list of n unique random numbers in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119107/how-do-i-generate-a-list-of-n-unique-random-numbers-in-ruby)

I want to do:

```
Random.rand(0..10).times do
  puts Random.rand(0..10)
end
```

with the exception that if a random number has already been displayed it cannot be displayed again. How do I do this most easily?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a quick one-liner:

```
rands = (0..10).to_a.shuffle[0, Random.rand(0..10)]
```

Comment: I don't say it often enough - I _really love_ the way Ruby lets you do this sort of thing!

Comment: I imagine that in Python it could be even easier :)

Comment: also: `Array(0..10).shuffle.take(rand(10))`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Ruby 1.9 another one-liner with [Array#sample](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample)

```
rands = (0..10).to_a.sample(­Random.ran­­d(0..10))
```