# Code to write a random array of x numbers with no duplicates

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I generate a list of n unique random numbers in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119107/how-do-i-generate-a-list-of-n-unique-random-numbers-in-ruby)

I am trying to create a randomly generated  array of x numbers with no duplicates.  I am choosing numbers—one at a time—then comparing them to the first number, and then all the other numbers in the array.  I have looked at the other questions, but I am a beginner and the explanations are a bit over my head—but I am learning.

Here is my code.  There are explanations in capital letters of what I think "hope" is going on.  My problem is at the end.

```
array = []
array[0] = rand(10)  #THIS CHOOSES FIRST NUMBER (FN) AND PUTS IT IN THE FIRST ARRAY SPOT
p "fn = #{array[0]}"

for i in 1..6  #START OF FOR LOOP TO GET 6 NUMBERS IN THE ARRAY - WHY 6?  THE FIRST NUMBER THAT POPPED IN MY HEAD
  p "Iteration #{i} -------------------------"  # THIS IS JUST SO I KNOW WHERE I AM IN THE LOOPS

  @x = rand(10)  #THIS CHOOSES THE NEXT NUMBER AND ALL NUMBERS AFTER
  array.each do |uc|  # THIS IS THE LOOP THAT COMPAIRS ALL NUMBERS
    @type = @x == uc ? "yes" : "no"  #DOES THE CHOOSEN NUMBER EQUAL ANY NUMBER IN THE ARRAY
    p "does #{uc} = #{@x}? #{@type}"
    if @type == "yes"  # IF THE COMPAIR IS TRUE, I DONT WANT ANY THING DONE.  IT WILL CYCLE THRU AND GET A NEW NUMBER
      i = 1 
      p "YES #{@x} = #{uc}"
      break
    end  #END OF IF YESS
  end  #END OF ARRAY EACH

  if @type == "no"  #IF NO, PUT NEXT NUMBER (@X) INTO THE NEXT ARRAY SPOT.
    p "in last if type= #{@type}"  #THESE STATMENTS JUST PRINT OUT THE DIFFERENT VARIABLES SO I KNOW I AM GETTING WHAT I EXPECT
    p "in last if x = #{@x}"
    p "in last if i = #{i}"
    @x = array[i]  #THIS "SHOULD" FILL THE NEXT ARRAY SPOT - BUT DOESNT SEEM TO
    p "#{array[i]} is in the array"  #THIS PRINT OUT IS BLANK - STATEMENT ABOVE DID NOT WORK.
    p array[i]
  end  #END OF IF NO
end  #END OF FOR LOOP
```

Comment: Why on earth are you using `"yes"` & `"no"` instead of `true` & `false`??

Comment: No, not personal preference, you are avoiding the correct types, which will cost you a lot of functionality and makes your code unreadable and bloated. We use `true` and `false` in Ruby, not any String.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  Would I then switch my if statement to if @type == "true"  or is there something else i have not run across.  Thanks much for your help.

Comment: You should consider using the built-in methods, rather than manually using various loops. See Duncan Beevers answer in the question that Intrepidd referenced, which would be (0..9).to_a.sample(6) in your case.

Comment: You'll learn a LOT if you post this on http://codereview.stackexchange.com