# Rails unique random records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, random

I want to display a couple records randomly. First thing I tried was this:

```
thing1 = Thing.offset(rand(Thing.count)).first
thing2 = Thing.offset(rand(Thing.count)).first
```

But that sometimes returns duplicates obviously. I guess not much of a problem with a lot of records, but now I'm curious. So I tried this:

```
random1 = rand(count)
random2 = rand(count)
until random1!=random2 do
  random2 = rand(count)
end
thing1 = Thing.offset(random1).first
thing2 = Thing..offset(random2)).first
```

But that's not perfect either, if you get, say, 4 and 5 as your random numbers, and record 4 was deleted, you still end up with a duplicate, because offset. Plus, and this is nitpicking, records directly after n deleted records are (n+1) times more likely to come up in this "random" selection.

What's the best way to get multiple unique random records?

Comment: possible duplicate of [n unique random numbers in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119107/how-do-i-generate-a-list-of-n-unique-random-numbers-in-ruby)

Comment: @twonegatives Nope. Close, different. SQL related.

Answer (score 1):

If it will always be two records, you can simply use:

```
(thing1, thing2) = Thing.order("RANDOM()").limit(2)
```

To generalize for any number of records, you could make a function for it:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.random_n_record(n)
    order("RANDOM()").limit(n)
  end
end
```

And then, for you example above, to get random elements for `thing1` and `thing2`

```
(thing1, thing2) = Thing.random_n_records(2)
things = Thing.random_n_records(10)
```

**NOTE:** If you're using Mysql, replace `"RANDOM()"` with `"RAND()"`. `"RANDOM()"` is for Postgresql.

Comment: Wouldn't that only return ordered things? record 4, record 5, etc?

Comment: I think you might be right. Either way, I updated my answer to use random ordering from the database.

Comment: Ah, that should do it. It'd be a pretty slow query though, wouldn't it? I'm wondering whose solution I should use.

Comment: Good question. I'm not sure. You could test them both, and see which seems to work better for your use case. On a giant database, your solution would probably be quicker, as finding a random number in ruby at most two or three times (realistically) would probably be faster than randomly ordering thousands or millions of rows.

Comment: Yeah, I'm thinking at least a couple thousand. Anyways, thanks for the help. And nice website, probably the bro-est thing I've ever seen on the internet. And I once watched a man chop a tree down with an axe tied to his beard.

Comment: Thanks! And that sounds awesome. That would make for a great video of the day.

Answer (score 1):

```
count = Thing.count
thing1 = Thing.offset(rand(count)).first
thing2 = Thing.offset(rand(count)).first
until thing1.id != thing2.id do
  thing2 = Thing.offset(rand(count)).first
end
```

Got it.

Comment: If you only have one record, your loop will not terminate, so you may want to add a check for if count is one.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot guarantee uniqueness if you're picking records simultaneously. If you need the records to be unique, you will have to randomly pick a record, then exclude it from the set of records, pick another randomly, etc. etc. This problem should be implemented easily using recursion.