# How to generate unique six digit alpha-numeric code in Ruby

Tags: ruby, alphanumeric

I need to generate a unique six digit alpha-numeric code. To save in my database as voucher no: for every transaction.

Comment: Why are you not simply auto-incrementing the code? They'd be numeric then. If you have too many codes (more than 6 digits), you can use a Base32 enoding of this number, e.g.

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88311/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby

Comment: @Teoulas I don't think so. There's nothing in this question that states that the codes need to be (or appear) random.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this

```
  require 'sha1'
  srand
  seed = "--#{rand(10000)}--#{Time.now}--"
  Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(seed)[0,6]
```

[How to generate a random string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88311/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby)  This link was useful

Comment: This is a very bad answer with high probability of collision. With 1 million iterations there are 767 **thousand** collisions on 215 thousand keys. Bumping the random number from `10000` to `10000000` reduces the collisions to "only" 31,000 out of 1,000,000, but any collisions is still bad. This is true whether Time.now is always the same or if it returns a new value each call (e.g. no more than one transaction per second).

Comment: In normal case this an acceptable one. Is there any other way for this.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to let the database handle the ids(incrementing). But if you insisting on generating them your self, you can use a random generator to generate an code, check it against db for uniqueness. then either accept or regenerate

Comment: This is a bad idea in theory as you start to fill up the available namespace, since your chance of collisions increases and in the extreme you may end up stuck in a loop of regenerating for a very long time before you find a free key.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the database to generate unique keys, but if you insist on doing it the hard way:

```
class AlnumKey

  def initialize
    @chars = ('0' .. '9').to_a + ('a' .. 'z').to_a
  end

  def to_int(key)
    i = 0
    key.each_char do |ch|
      i = i * @chars.length + @chars.index(ch)
    end
    i
  end

  def to_key(i)
    s = ""
    while i > 0 
      s += @chars[i % @chars.length]
      i /= @chars.length
    end
    s.reverse 
  end

  def next_key(last_key)
    to_key(to_int(last_key) + 1) 
  end
end

al = AlnumKey.new
puts al.next_key("ab")
puts al.next_key("1")
puts al.next_key("zz")
```

Of course, you'll have to store your current key somewhere, and this is in no way thread / multisession-safe etc.

Answer (score 0):

With the following restrictions:

1. Valid only until 2038-12-24 00:40:35 UTC
2. Generates no more than once within a second

you can use this simple code:

```
Time.now.to_i.to_s(36)
# => "lks3bn"
```

Comment: What will happen if the system time is changed?

Comment: at a time I need to get different voucher ID's

Comment: @Zabba That will cause a problem, but I assumed it will not be so frequent. In that case, the system will have to be down for maintenance for the time span that equals the difference between the new and the old time zones. It will be less than a day, at worst. If the new time zone goes ahead, the system does not have to be down.

Answer (score 0):

```
class IDSequence
  attr_reader :current
  def initialize(start=0,digits=6,base=36)
    @id, @chars, @base = start, digits, base
  end
  def next
    s = (@id+=1).to_s(@base)
    @current = "0"*(@chars-s.length) << s
  end
end

id = IDSequence.new
1234.times{ id.next }

puts id.current
#=> 0000ya

puts id.next
#=> 0000yb

9876543.times{ id.next }
puts id.current
#=> 05vpqq
```

Answer (score 0):

This would eleviate the time collision issue by getting the milli seconds

```
(Time.now.to_f*1000.0).to_i
```