# Generate Unique Random String With Letters And Numbers In Lower Case

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How can I fix this code so it generates unique random letters and numbers in lower case?

```
api_string = (0...32).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join
```

At the moment, it generates only letters.

Comment: The range for numbers is 48 to 57. These must be included in your range.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you give an example so I can mark it as correct?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How best to generate a random string in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88311/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby)

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If you are using ruby 1.9.2 you can use SecureRandom:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'securerandom'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> SecureRandom.hex(13)
=> "5bbf194bcf8740ae8c9ce49e97"
irb(main):003:0> SecureRandom.hex(15)
=> "d2413503a9618bacfdb1745eafdb0f"
irb(main):004:0> SecureRandom.hex(32)
=> "432e0a359bbf3669e6da610d57ea5d0cd9e2fceb93e7f7989305d89e31073690"
```

Comment: This is handy for simple needs but the alpha range is only a-f, so the security/complexity of the generated string isn't as high as it could be.

Comment: Better to use base64, which is also built in: SecureRandom.base64(16).gsub(/=+$/,'')

Comment: Not an issue for an API key, but there's also the handy urlsafe_base64 method: SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(16) => "XpMnLfc3FySd-C4V2Ipxag"

Comment: Why is it better to use base64

Comment: Even better `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(length)`

Comment: @ckarbass Hex only allows 0-9 and a-f. Base64 uses a wider character set.

Comment: Mentioned below but newer versions of ruby support `SecureRandom.base58(n)` which is pretty ideal for this use case.

Answer (score 28):

All letters and digits, that's how numbers are represented in base 36.

```
api_string = Array.new(32){rand(36).to_s(36)}.join
```

Answer (score 15):

`8.times.map { [*'0'..'9', *'a'..'z'].sample }.join`

Comment: `'0'..'9'` generates an array from 0 to 9, and `'a'..'z'` generates an array from a to z, but what exactly does the * before each of them does?

Comment: `'0'..'9'` is range and `*` is splat operator. It splits the elements of the range into single items which are returned as a group, so basically `*` is helping you to separate out elements so that they can be sampled out using `sample` method

Comment: have a look at this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72738840/7365329

Answer (score 4):

Newer versions of Ruby support [SecureRandom.base58](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/SecureRandom.html), which will get you much denser tokens than hex, without any special characters.

```
> SecureRandom.base58(24)
> "Zp9N4aYvQfz3E6CmEzkadoa2"
```

Comment: This answer it's much way better than the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it:

```
POSSIBLE = (('A'..'Z').to_a + (0..9).to_a)
api_string = (0...32).map { |n| POSSIBLE.sample }.join
```

If you have Active Support available you can also do this to make an API-key-like string:

```
ActiveSupport::SecureRandom.hex(32)
```

Answer (score 2):

i forgot from where, but i've read this somehow this morning

```
l,m = 24,36
rand(m**l).to_s(m).rjust(l,'0')
```

it create random number from 0 to power(36,24), then convert it to base-36 string (that is 0-9 and a-z)

Comment: This is faster than steenslag's https://gist.github.com/cameron-martin/a7a91f0bc952e8a5c795

Comment: Except it's not always true that `rand(36**len).to_s(36).length == len`, so you will have to do `rand(36**len).to_s(36).rjust(len, '0')`

Answer (score 1):

```
CHARS = (?0..?9).to_a + (?a..?z).to_a
api_string = 32.times.inject("") {|s, i| s << CHARS[rand(CHARS.size)]}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
((('a'..'z').to_a + (0..9).to_a)*3).shuffle[0,(rand(100).to_i)].join
```

Replace `rand(100)` with `rand(n)` where `n` is the maximum length of your desired string.

Answer (score 1):

This will generate a lower random string from 32 to 50 characters including numbers and letters, both:

```
require 'string_pattern'

puts "32-50:/xN/".gen
```

Answer (score 0):

using SecureRandom of ruby language.

```
require 'securerandom' randomstring = SecureRandom.hex(5)
```

It will generate the n*2 random string contains “0-9″ and “a-f”

Answer (score 0):

you can use Time in miliseconds with redix base 36

**Example:**
`Time.now.to_f.to_s.gsub('.', '').ljust(17, '0').to_i.to_s(36) # => "4j26l5vq964"`

have a look at this answer to better explaination:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72738840/7365329

Answer (score -1):

```
Process.clock_gettime(Process::CLOCK_REALTIME, :nanosecond).to_s(36)
```