# How would i generate a random and unique string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In a Ruby on Rails app I am working on I allow users to upload files and want to give these files a short, random alphanumeric name. (Eg 'g7jf8' or '3bp76'). What is the best way to do this?

I sas thinking of generating a hash / encrypted string from the original filename and timestamp. Then query the database to double check it doesnt exist. If it does, generate another and repeat.

The issue i see with this approach is if there is high propability of duplicate strings, it could add quite a lote of datbase load.

Comment: There is also the potential (if improbable) race condition of two requests trying to add the same name at the same time. The database should have a unique constraint on that column and you should be prepared to catch `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5966910/generate-unique-random-string-with-letters-and-numbers-in-lower-case

Comment: Does the "random" name have a security purpose? If not, you have more options.

Comment: It doesn't need to be secure, but may be used in a URL. Thanks for all the help so far. Many ideas to try and work on.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use this :)

```
def generate_token(column, length = 64)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64 length
  end while Model.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

Replace `Model` by your model name

Answer (score 10):

```
SecureRandom.uuid
```

Will give you a globally unique String. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier

```
SecureRandom.hex 32
```

Will give a random String, but it's algorithm is not optimised for uniqueness. Of course the chance of collision with 32 digits, assuming true randomness, is basically theoretical. You could make 1 billion per second for 100 years and have only a 50% chance of a collision.

Answer (score 6):

Use Ruby's [SecureRandom.hex](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html#method-c-hex) function with optional number of character you wanted to generate.

Comment: My favourite for this question might be `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This will always produce new uniq 40 size alpha-numeric string, because it has Time stamp also.

```
loop do
  random_token = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest([Time.now, rand(111..999)].join)
  break random_token unless Model.exists?(column_name: random_token)
end
```

Note: Replace Model by your model_name and column_name by any existing column of your model.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a unique id by incrementing it each time a new file is added, and convert that id into an encrypted string using [`OpenSSL::Cipher`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html) with a constant key that you save somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you end up generating a hex or numeric digest, you can keep the code shorter by representing the number as e.g. Base 62:

```
# This is a lightweight base62 encoding for Ruby integers.
B62CHARS = ('0'..'9').to_a + ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a

def base62_string nbr
  b62 = ''
  while nbr > 0
    b62 << B62CHARS[nbr % 62]
    nbr /= 62
  end
  b62.reverse
end
```

If it is important for you to restrict the character set used (for instance not have uppercase chars in file names), then this code can easily be adapted, provided you can find a way of feeding in a suitable random number.

If your file names are supposed to be semi-secure, you need to arrange that there are many more possible names than actual names in storage.

Comment: This doesn't generate anything unique, which is what the OP asked for. Given the same `nbr` this will return the same string every time, and you need to pass a ridiculously large number to return a string of any significant size. Ex: `> base62_string 99999999999999999999 # => "1V973MbJYWoT"`

Comment: @Chrisbloom7: Agreed, this needs feeding in a number, which I don't explain how to obtain (but I do mention in the text this is required). Generating a random number of suitable size is trivial in Ruby though: `SecureRandom.random_number(2**128)`. The approach also works with sequences, hashes etc. The fact that it requires a huge input to make a short string is actually desirable to the OP, they asked for a short string

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you actually need a unique filenames, right? Why not forget about complex solutions and simply use [Time#nsec](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-nsec)?

```
t = Time.now        #=> 2007-11-17 15:18:03 +0900
"%10.9f" % t.to_f   #=> "1195280283.536151409"
```

Comment: If the app is large and busy, and has several independant servers, eventually two will process a file at the same time and get a collision.

Comment: Concat _nanosecs_ with server’s name to be totally sure.

Comment: At that point, SecureRandom.uuid is a simpler solution I think.

Comment: In my case you gain sortable list out of the box. But it’s a matter of taste, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Time in miliseconds and than convert it into base 36 to reduce it length.
and since it depends on time to it will be very unique.

**Example:**
`Time.now.to_f.to_s.gsub('.', '').ljust(17, '0').to_i.to_s(36) # => "4j26lna7g62"`

Take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72738840/7365329