# Random fake names

Tags: database, random

Some websites create random fake names when you create a project file. For example, creating a project within Heroku could generate "immense-bastion-4566" as a project name. I would like to know how they create those names, because I would like to use the same technique in an iOS app.

My guess is they have a DB with names they just randomly pick names, but where do they get these databases from? Any hints?

Comment: The number part seems fairly straighforward, I would imagine a PRNG would work for that part. As for the names, a noun list, with PRNG seems like it gets the job done. You can find noun lists online. I can't be sure if `Heroku` employs the same method though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you specifically asked for Heroku, you can read up on their implementation here [How can I programmatically generate Heroku-like subdomain names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621341/how-can-i-programmatically-generate-heroku-like-subdomain-names#answer-20059752).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it'd be two tables: one adjective table, one noun table. When creating a project, they could create a name by picking a random entry from each table, then appending a randomly-generated number to the end.

According to [this site](http://akinas.com/pages/en/blog/mysql_random_row/), one can efficiently pick a random entry from a table like so (assuming a table definition of id/word):

```
SELECT `word` FROM `nouns` 
    WHERE id >= (SELECT FLOOR(MAX(id) * RAND()) FROM `nouns`)
ORDER BY `id` LIMIT 1
```

Repeat for an adjective.

Answer (score 0):

[RandomUsername](https://github.com/polleverywhere/random_username) in Ruby uses cultivated lists of adjectives & nouns. It doesn't use a dictionary or general-purpose word database because many of those words have a strong negative connotation, and therefore not appropriate in a business context.