# What's a fast and elegant way to build a long string (for testing) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I need a string that is `str_len` characters long for testing.

What ways are there that are more elegant (and possibly faster) ways of building it than the following:

```
  long_str = ''
  (str_len + 1).times do
    long_str << 'a'
  end
```

It would be helpful if the algorithm could also randomise the content of the string (i.e. use any character).

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88311/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `*` method on the String class.

```
long_str = 'a' * 6
# => 'aaaaaa'
```

Answer (score 3):

This produces a four letter long random string with the characters a to z.

```
charset=('a'..'z').to_a
srand(124931)
puts (0...4).map{ charset.to_a[rand(charset.size)] }.join
```

Remove or replace the `srand(124931)` with `srand()` before actually using this code.