# pseudo_encrypt() function in plpgsql that takes bigint

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I'm working on a system that generates random ids like in answer #2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575022/generating-an-instagram-or-youtube-like-unguessable-string-id-in-ruby-activerec).

My problem is, that the mentioned [pseudo_encrypt()](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt) function works with int not bigint. I tried to rewrite it but it returns always the same result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pseudo_encrypt(VALUE bigint) returns bigint AS $$
DECLARE
l1 bigint;
l2 int;
r1 bigint;
r2 int;
i int:=0;
BEGIN
    l1:= (VALUE >> 32) & 4294967296::bigint;
    r1:= VALUE & 4294967296;
    WHILE i < 3 LOOP
        l2 := r1;
        r2 := l1 # ((((1366.0 * r1 + 150889) % 714025) / 714025.0) * 32767)::int;
        l1 := l2;
        r1 := r2;
        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
RETURN ((l1::bigint << 32) + r1);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql strict immutable;
```

Can somebody check this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`4294967295` must be used as the bitmask to select 32 bits (instead of `4294967296`).
That's the reason why currently you get the same value for different inputs.

I'd also suggest using `bigint` for the types of `l2` and `r2`, they shouldn't really differ from `r1` and `l1`

And, for better randomness, use a much higher multiplier in the PRNG function to get intermediate block that really occupy 32 bits, like 32767*32767 instead of 32767.

The complete modified version:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pseudo_encrypt(VALUE bigint) returns bigint AS $$
DECLARE
l1 bigint;
l2 bigint;
r1 bigint;
r2 bigint;
i int:=0;
BEGIN
    l1:= (VALUE >> 32) & 4294967295::bigint;
    r1:= VALUE & 4294967295;
    WHILE i < 3 LOOP
        l2 := r1;
        r2 := l1 # ((((1366.0 * r1 + 150889) % 714025) / 714025.0) * 32767*32767)::int;
        l1 := l2;
        r1 := r2;
        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
RETURN ((l1::bigint << 32) + r1);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql strict immutable;
```

First results:

```
select x,pseudo_encrypt(x::bigint) from generate_series (1, 10) as x;
 x  |   pseudo_encrypt    
----+---------------------
  1 | 3898573529235304961
  2 | 2034171750778085465
  3 |  169769968641019729
  4 | 2925594765163772086
  5 | 1061193016228543981
  6 | 3808195743949274374
  7 | 1943793931158625313
  8 |   88214277952430814
  9 | 2835217030863818694
 10 |  970815170807835400
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Ah the bitmask was a stupid mistake... Thank you very much! Works perfectly now! Btw: you wanted to suggest bigint, not int.

Comment: @Daniel Vérité What i have to modify in the fuction if i need a bigint with a max length of 13 digits?

Comment: @MattC: it's non-trivial, you may submit this as a new question. Also with this technique the upper bound is going to be `2^N` where `N` is an even number, not `10^N`.

Comment: @DanielVérité Thank you for your answer, i've posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760630/generate-unique-random-numbers-in-postgresql-with-fixed-length

Comment: I noticed the problem about the own inverse function (true for the int version of the pseudo_encrypt). This version up here does not correctly inverse. The answer below by Kurt Riede does this correctly. To try it out use: ```select x,pseudo_encrypt(x::bigint), pseudo_encrypt(pseudo_encrypt(x::bigint)) from generate_series(-10,10) as x;```

Comment: @PatrickBoos: true, but the self inverse property is not necessarily desirable. For instance, it precludes the use of the cycle walking method, such as explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption#FPE_from_a_Feistel_network

Comment: @DanielVérité good point. It might actually be desired. I agree there :)

Comment: @DanielVérité In the original they had `RETURN ((r1 << 16) + l1);`, but you flipped r1 and l1 there. What is the reason for this?

Comment: @thnee: the real original [as first posted](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/448163db-cac5-4e99-8c4c-57cbc6f6af78@mm) had `return ((l1::bigint<<16) + r1)`. Swapping r1 and l1 make the function a self-inverse, which may or may not be desirable. Please see the other comments above.

Answer (score 10):

Old but still an interesting question. Comparing to Daniels answer I am using a slightly modified version, changing the return statement to this (exchanged r1 and l1), as also mentioned at the end of the article [Pseudo encrypt](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt):

```
RETURN ((r1::bigint << 32) + l1);
```

The reason for this change is that the underlying [Feistel algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) should not exchange left an right at the end of the last round. With this change the function regains the ability to act as its own inverse function:

```
pseudo_encrypt(pseudo_encrypt(x) == x // always returns true
```

Here is the full code in pgsql:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pseudo_encrypt(VALUE bigint) returns bigint AS $$
DECLARE
l1 bigint;
l2 bigint;
r1 bigint;
r2 bigint;
i int:=0;
BEGIN
    l1:= (VALUE >> 32) & 4294967295::bigint;
    r1:= VALUE & 4294967295;
    WHILE i < 3 LOOP
        l2 := r1;
        r2 := l1 # ((((1366.0 * r1 + 150889) % 714025) / 714025.0) * 32767*32767)::int;
        l1 := l2;
        r1 := r2;
    i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
RETURN ((r1::bigint << 32) + l1);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql strict immutable;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. This answer produces positive bigints as apposed to the accepted answer which seems to go negative for input values >2^32-1