# How to generate random unique number in PostgreSQL using function

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, how to generate random unique integer number for column,
return which not exits in table column?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See the [pseudo_encrypt](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt) function, which implements a permutation based on the [Feistel network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) technique. Combined with a postgres sequence, this guarantees unicity of the result, as well as randomness to the human eye.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pseudo_encrypt(VALUE int) returns int AS $$
DECLARE
l1 int;
l2 int;
r1 int;
r2 int;
i int:=0;
BEGIN
 l1:= (VALUE >> 16) & 65535;
 r1:= VALUE & 65535;
 WHILE i < 3 LOOP
   l2 := r1;
   r2 := l1 # ((((1366 * r1 + 150889) % 714025) / 714025.0) * 32767)::int;
   l1 := l2;
   r1 := r2;
   i := i + 1;
 END LOOP;
 RETURN ((r1 << 16) + l1);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql strict immutable;


create sequence seq maxvalue 2147483647;

create table tablename(
 id int default pseudo_encrypt(nextval('seq')::int),
 [other columns]
);
```

A variant with a 64-bit output space can be found at: [pseudo_encrypt() function in plpgsql that takes bigint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761346/pseudo-encrypt-function-in-plpgsql-that-takes-bigint).

---

EDIT: `pseudo_encrypt` implements only one permutation, and it does not accept a user-supplied key. If you prefer having your own permutations, depending on secret keys, you may consider `skip32` (a 32-bit block cipher based on Skipjack, with 10 bytes wide keys).

A plpgsql function (ported from Perl/C) is available at:
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Skip32

Comment: should nt it be int instead of bigint for the id column.Means I understand that the seq wont return anything beyond the int range but is there any specific reason to make it bigint instead of int?



`create table tablename(
 id int default pseudo_encrypt(nextval('seq')::int),
 [other columns]
);`

Comment: @AmolKshirsagar: yes, it could be an integer now. When initially answered, pseudo_encrypt returned a bigint, but it has been modified since. The answer is now updated accordingly.

Comment: Daniel Vérité : Is there a way to test out this approach using some script. I have made the changes. Just wanted to be 100% sure that I don't make a mistake in production since that would be serious issue

Comment: @AmolKshirsagar: well you could call this function with the 4 billion possible inputs or a fraction thereof and check the properties (I guess unicity and dispersion).

Comment: Don't use this technique if the goal of randomness is to prevent [information disclosure](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/328534/85530). This technique obscures, but doesn't eliminate, the disclosure, since it uses predictable pseudo-random numbers.