# How to implement a high performing non incremental ID in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I'd like to move away from incremental IDs that can easily be guessed and implement something truly random, but still highly indexable to the tune of millions of records.

I thought about using random alphanumeric ID like the ones used in short links `(s36rb94kpw59v0h3w6s)` but I have a suspicion it'll result in an extremely bloated index and poor optimization.

I also consider UUIDS but i'm not sure how they perform in terms of `SELECT`. I still want the speed of fetching incremental ID but I just want some sort of non-guessable ID format that wouldn't quadruple my server costs.

*P.S. non postgresql solutions are out of the question unfortunately.*

Comment: Look at the `pseudo_random` function on the PostgreSQL wiki. For bonus performance points re-implement it as a C extension.

Comment: Or: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760630/generate-unique-random-numbers-in-postgresql-with-fixed-length

Comment: I don't think a UUID is that much slower then an integer. But it apparently depends on your workload and use-case