# Getting primary key sequence number in postgres

Tags: postgresql, random, sequences

We've got a table where we're exposing a ShortID to our consumers that generates a Youtube like identifier (heavily inspired by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575022/generating-an-instagram-or-youtube-like-unguessable-string-id-in-ruby-activerec)). We use the primary KEY of the row to generate it (in the view). For example

```
SELECT title,description,imageuri,generateseoid(id)as seo FROM broadcastimage WHERE...
```

The `generateseoid` functionis essentially doing the `stringify_bigint` call (from the above SO answers) with some minor changes.

Our need is to do this at insertion time. Is it safe to get the value like so:

```
generateseoid(currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('broadcastimage', 'id')))
```

within the insert call? We have lots of threads (via SQS queues in AWS) inserting records into the broadcast stream table. I'm a bit concerned that with multiple postgres connections, we'd get the same sequence number being generated. There's a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on that column.

Alternative is to add another random() number to it I guess?

EDIT:

Here's a simple example that tests the nextval vs currval:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  text text
)
  insert into test (text) VALUES ('test ' || nextval(pg_get_serial_sequence('test ', 'id')))
  insert into test (text) VALUES ('test ' || currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('test ', 'id')))

select * From test
```

The results point to:

```
1 | test 2
3 | test 3
```

Comment: *Is it safe to get the value like so ...* -- with `currval`: as long as you use the `DEFAULT` for your primary key (or omit it in the `INSERT`), or use `nextval(...)` directly at insertion for this primary key, it is safe. -- with `nextval`: always safe, but the the generated value won't be in sync with the primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres will generate new ids for sequences each time.   You might get gaps in the sequence caused by rollbacks etc, but if that isn't important, then you should be good to go.

You should be using `nextval` to get a new value.  `currval` reports the last generated value.

Sequence documentation.
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I used currval because if you run this sample, I'm getting id+1 as my value as example above.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use `nextval` to roll forward the value and return it.

Regarding your concern - it is [safe](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html) to use `nextval` for multiple concurrent transactions:

> To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the
>   same sequence, a nextval operation is never rolled back; that is, once
>   a value has been fetched it is considered used and will not be
>   returned again. This is true even if the surrounding transaction later
>   aborts, or if the calling query ends up not using the value.