# Rails: Adding to model after user submits form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my Rails 3.2 project, I have a form to create a new post in `new.html.erb` in `app/views/posts/`

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |post_form| %>
  ...
  <div class="field">
    <%= post_form.label :title %><br />
    <%= post_form.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= post_form.label :content %><br />
    <%= post_form.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= post_form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Then the `create` function in `posts_controller.rb`

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])  
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
  end
end
```

When the user submits a post, the `title` and `content` of the post are added to the `Post` model. However, I also want to add to another field of that post. For the field `random_hash` (which the user doesn't get to specify), I want to make it a string of 8 lowercase letters, the first 2 of which are the first 2 letters of the title, and the last 6 are random lowercase letters. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```rb
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  @post.random_hash = generate_random_hash(params[:post][:title])
  if @post.save
    format.html { redirect_to @post }
  else
    format.html { render action: "new" }
  end
end

def generate_random_hash(title)
  first_two_letters = title[0..1]
  next_six_letters = (0...6).map{65.+(rand(25)).chr}.join
  (first_two_letters + next_six_letters).downcase
end
```

Put that in your controller. You obviously have to have `random_hash` attribute for Post model to work.

I am using [Kent Fredric's solution to generate six random letters.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88311/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby)

Comment: Should it be `params[:title]` or `@post.title` there in the third line?

Comment: Either should work fine in this case. `params[:title]` will contain the same title as @post.title. Feel free to choose either one of them.

Comment: Shouldn't `params[:post][:title]` be the same as `@post.title`? (I'm new to Rails, so I'm sorry if this is a basic thing.)