# How to fetch a random record in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to fetch a random record in rails, to render in my home page.

I have a post model with content and title attributes. Lets say i wanted to fetch a random post(content and title) for some reason, How can i go about it in ruby. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to fetch a random post from your database, or to create random content ?

Comment: Sorry if i was unclear, I want to fetch a random post not create.

Comment: i edited your post to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4):

You might find this gem handy : [Faker](http://faker.rubyforge.org/)

It allows to generate random strings with some meaning.

For example, a name :

```
Faker::Name.name => “Bob Hope”
```

Or an e-mail

```
Faker::Internet.email
```

In addition to this gem, if you want to be able to generate mock models very easily, I recommend the gem [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl)

It allows you to create factories for your model, sou you can generate a model with random attributes quickly.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me and Sorry if i was unclear, I want to fetch a random post not create. If i am correct the faker gem creates random attributes. I am looking for fetch attributes at random to render in a view.

Answer (score 1):

Posting another answer since the first one answered to an unclear question.

As @m_x said, you can use `RANDOM()`  for SQL.

If you don't mind loading all the dataset, you can do it in ruby as well :

```
Post.all.sample
```

This will select one random record from all Posts.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but since no answer was chosen, answering it might be helpful for other users.

I think the best way to go would be generating a random offset in Ruby and using it in your Active Record statement, like so:

```
Thing.limit(1).offset(rand(Thing.count)).first
```

This solution is also performant and portable.

Answer (score 0):

In your post controller,

```rb
def create
  @post = Post.new(params[:post])
  if you_want_some_random_title_and_content
    title_length = 80 #choose your own
    content_length = 140 #choose your own
    @post.title = (0...title_length).map{(65+rand(26)).chr}.join
    @post.content = (0...content_length).map{(65+rand(26)).chr}.join
  end

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

[Using Kent Fedric's way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88311/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby) to generate random string

Comment: Titles and contents in the real world usually have spaces in them…

Comment: That may be true, but OP did not mention that.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, there is no database-agnostic method for fetching a random record, so ActiveRecord does not implement any.

For postgresql you can use :

```
Post.order( 'RANDOM()' ).first
```

To fetch one random post.

Additionnally, i usually create a scope for this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :random_order, ->{ order 'RANDOM()' }
end
```

so if you change your RDBMS, you just have to change the scope.

Comment: More along the lins of what i need. Thnaks.