# Ruby On Rails - how to rename currently uploaded file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, file-rename

This is my method for uploading files:

```
name = file.original_filename
directory = "images/"
path = File.join(directory, name)
File.open(path, "wb") { |f| f.write(file.read) }
```

I need to rename the uploaded file - I want to give it a unique name. But how can I obtain the file name and the extension?

One way on how to rename the file is from the filename remove the extension (`.jpg` - remove last 4 chars), rename the file and then merge the name+extension.

But this is a bit dirty way. Is there something cleaner and more elegant?

Answer (score 1):

A 'little' late but I put this answer for those who are still searching and get here.

```
photo = params[:photo]
name = photo.original_filename
directory = "public/uploads/photos"
path = File.join(directory, name) 
uniq_name = (0...10).map { (65 + rand(26)).chr }.join
time_footprint = Time.now.to_formatted_s(:number)
File.open(path, "wb") do |file|
  file.write(photo.read)
  @uniq_path = File.join(directory, uniq_name + time_footprint + File.extname(file))
  File.rename(file, @uniq_path)
end
```

I take the random string generation from [How to generate a random string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88311/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby). And set @uniq_path to use it on a create function after.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing this?

`File.rename(file, folder_path + "/" + new_name + File.extname(file))`

For example, calling this script on the same folder of the file:

```
new_name = "TESTING"

File.open("test.txt") do |file|
  File.rename(file, new_name + File.extname(file))
end
```

Will rename the file to: TESTING.txt

Comment: Thanks Kaeros for the answer, but this would work only on files that are already saved, or not?

Comment: Hmm, yes.. maybe you can do an `after_save` hook with this. :)

Comment: Well, I would need to rename the file before its saving, because in this case can happen, that I will save a file with the name that already exists and instead of 2 saved files I will get just one (overwritten).

Comment: Are you using carrierwave?

Comment: I don't use any gem for upload, I just need to upload files, no other operations with them (actually, except renaming).