# Generate a unique code in method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've watched a lot of Railscasts (thanks Ryan) and I need to recall some code I saw in one of them but my problem is I can't remember where to find it.

I can generate a 5 digit code using the code below and this is found in a method:

```
5.times.map { [*'A'..'Z'].sample }.join
```

but I need to be able to make sure that it's unique before saving. I remember Ryan using a loop of some sort in the model method to check that it is unique before saving.

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password is the page you're looking for:

```
def generate_token(column)
  begin
    self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end while User.exists?(column => self[column])
end
```

So you could replace the `SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64` part with your own code.

Comment: Good find! Really appreciate that - the code I want to create should only be 5 letters long and consist of capital letters only - is my method listed in the question the best way to do this do you know?

Comment: @tommyd456 I'd normally recommend something like any of `SecureRandom`'s methods, but with your requirements your code should work just fine. There's a lengthy set of answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88311/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby

Answer (score 1):

first, replace your stuff with: `SecureRandom.hex(5)`

Then I get what you're looking for, something like this I bet:

```
value   = true
while value
  random = SecureRandom.hex(5)
  value  = Model.where(column: random).exists?
end
#here you have an unique `random`
```

Comment: I would like capital letters only so I don't think .hex will suit my needs (not that I mentioned this in my question) - or am I mistaken?