# How can I create unique strings (with no numbers) with factory girl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

Or is an external gem necessary to generate random and unique usernames maybe?

Here's my current factory:

```
factory :user_4 do
    sequence(:id) { |n| n }
    sequence(:first_name) { |n| "Gemini" + n.to_s }
    sequence(:last_name) { |n| "Pollux" + n.to_s }
    sequence(:profile_name) { |n| "GeminiPollux" + n.to_s  }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "geminipollus" + n.to_s + "@hotmail.co.uk" }
end
```

Using the sequence method works for the id, profile_name and email, but my REGEX validations mean that the first name and last name are automatically invalid, because they have a digit in them. Nothing to do with the uniqueness.

So how should I create these unique names?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are [infinite possible solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88311/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby) to generate a random string without relying on third party gems.

Here's one

```
('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle.join
# => "sugrjtyoiqlbxkzcfnawdhpevm"
```

Example

```
factory :user_4 do
  sequence(:id) { |n| n }
  first_name { "Gemini" + random_name }
  # ...
end

def random_name
  ('a'..'z').to_a.shuffle.join
end
```

If the random factor is too low, you can increase the complexity.

Comment: This answer was very helpful to me but one piece of information that wasn't intuitive to me is that the method definition must not only be outside the factory declaration, it must also be outside the `FactoryGirl.define do` block as well.

Answer (score 21):

```
factory :user_4 do
  # ...
  sequence(:first_name, 'a') { |n| "Gemini" + n }
  sequence(:last_name, 'a') { |n| "Pollux" + n }
  # ...
end
```

FactoryGirl's `#sequence` method accepts a second argument as its starting value. This can be a String, a Fixnum, or something else that supports being incremented by a `#next` method.

With a starting value of `'a'` the sequence will be `a, b, c ... z, aa, ab, ac ...`

Comment: best answer!  you can also use 'A' and it will do `A, B ... Z, AA, AB ...`.

Answer (score 2):

```
factory :user_4 do
  letters = [a,b,c,d]
  sequence(:id) { |n| n }
  sequence(:first_name) { |n| "Gemini" + letters[n] }
  sequence(:last_name) { |n| "Pollux" + letters[n] }
  sequence(:profile_name) { |n| "GeminiPollux" + letters[n]  }
  sequence(:email) { |n| "geminipollus" + letters[n] + "@hotmail.co.uk" }
end
```

Or simply use ascii conversion, or use Faker gem

Answer (score 0):

If you give just a value to `sequence`, FactoryBot automatically generates a sequence of values by applying `#next` to that value. Since Ruby's `String` class prepares `#next` method, which returns a successor of a string, you can write like the following:

```
factory :user_4 do
    sequence(:id) { |n| n }
    sequence(:first_name) { "Gemini" }
    sequence(:last_name) { "Pollux" }
    profile_name { "#{first_name} #{last_name}" }
    email { "#{first_name.downcase}#{last_name.downcase}@hotmail.co.uk" }
end
```

For instance, a sequence of `first_name` is "Gemini", "Geminj", "Gemink", and so on.

Refs.

- https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#without-a-block
- https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/String.html#method-i-next