# How to generate some random addresses in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to generate some random addresses(string) in ruby?

DEUbQpgKyGDAjNqRXcpMYVD3HunVjCrH1G

DHcjoCTL2rHnAuKmWam64QfZv6H3DG3S6f

DSM1eJ6yXiaATHGXVmmznF1wuEuEzYvGHz

Comment: I would just use SecureRandom. See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1619602/812503

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be unique, you can use SecureRandom.
The simplest way would be using

```
SecureRandom.uuid
```

which generates ID like

```
irb(main):001:0> SecureRandom.uuid 
=> "0d218853-5ef8-46df-85b1-e7e7af18c0ba"
```

If you want it guaranteed to be unique, you may want to add timestamp:

```
Digest::MD5.hexdigest "#{SecureRandom.hex(10)}-#{DateTime.now.to_s}"
```

which generates

```
irb(main):002:0> Digest::MD5.hexdigest "#{SecureRandom.hex(10)}-#{DateTime.now.to_s}"
=> "15aaf4a73969c67afccdfdaf629a310e"
```

Answer (score 0):

such a thing?

```
Digest::MD5.hexdigest('foo') # => "acbd18db4cc2f85cedef654fccc4a4d8"
```

or 
[How to generate a random string in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/88311/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

For random folder names i do

```
timestamp = Time.new.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S%z")
"#{timestamp}_#{("%04x" % rand(16**4))}"
```