# Generate pseudo random string A-Z, 0-9

Tags: ruby, random

How can I generate an n-character pseudo random string containing only `A-Z`, `0-9` like [SecureRandom.base64](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html) without `"+"`, `"/"`, and `"="`? For example:

```
(0..n).map {(('1'..'9').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a)[rand(36)]}.join
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Array.new(n){[*"A".."Z", *"0".."9"].sample}.join
```

Comment: curiosity, any reason to do `.sample` over `[rand(36)]` ?

Comment: I can think of a couple: `sample` is more elegant, and it needn't be changed if the array being sampled is changed in size.

Comment: Curiosity, any reason to do `[rand(36)]` over `sample`?

Answer (score 4):

An elegant way to do it in Rails 5 (I don't test it in another Rails versions):

```
SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(n)
```

where `n` is the number of digits that you want.

ps: `SecureRandom` uses a array to mount your alphanumeric string, so keep in mind that `n` **should be the amount of digits that you want + 1**.

ex: if you want a 8 digit alphanumeric:

```
SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(9)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do simply like below:

```
[*'A'..'Z', *0..9].sample(10).join
```

Change the number 10 to any number to change the length of string

Answer (score 1):

Even brute force is pretty easy:

```
n = 20

c = [*?A..?Z + *?0..?9]
size = c.size
n.times.map { c[rand(size)] }.join
  #=> "IE210UOTDSJDKM67XCG1"
```

or, without replacement:

```
c.sample(n).join
  #=> "GN5ZC0HFDCO2G5M47VYW"
```

should that be desired. (I originally had `c = [*(?A..?Z)] + [*(?0..?9)]`, but saw from @sawa's answer that that could be simplified quite a bit.)

Answer (score 0):

To generate a random string from 10 to 20 characters including just from A to Z and numbers, both always:

```
require 'string_pattern'

puts "10-20:/XN/".gen
```