# Add a random string while updating attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am looking for a method that can generate a random string in the starting of the email field while updating the record.

```
def update
  @user = User.find_by_id(4)
  @user.email = #method to update email with random string
end
```

So if I have the email record `abc@gmail.com` and I want to update it like this:

```
dssaakj123_abc@gmail.com
```

How it can be done in rails?

Comment: Have you check this [Question: How best to generate a random string in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/88311/how-best-to-generate-a-random-string-in-ruby)?

Comment: just update the setter

Comment: Do you intend to prepend the email with the random string *once* or on *every* update?

Comment: I'll just warn you that the current solutions will all lead to emails updated on every update call. Resulting in `foo1_foo2_foo3_.._foo100_champ@gmail.com`. I this really what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `SecureRandom` library:

```
@user.email = "#{SecureRandom.hex(10)}_#{user.email}"
```

Comment: how can i get a random string only in digits ?

Comment: Use `'%011d' % rand(1e10)` instead of `SecureRandom.hex(10)`. To change the number of digits in the string change the number after `e` here: `1e10`

Comment: SecureRandom is part of [the standard lib](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html), no ActiveSupport needed.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `SecureRandom`?

```
require 'securerandom'
random_string = SecureRandom.hex # provide argument to limit the no. of characters

# outputs: 5b5cd0da3121fc53b4bc84d0c8af2e81 (i.e. 32 chars of 0..9, a..f)
```

For appending before email, you can do something like

```
@user.email = "#{SecureRandom.hex(5))_#{@user.email}" # 5 is no. of characters
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: just a small thing: i think the author if the question wanted to prepend a random string to the email address, not replace the whole string before `@` completely

Comment: @YuryLebedev Yes it might be the case. But he didn't mentioned. It might be the case, he wants to replace before `@`. Author needs to confirm on this.:(

Comment: Yes, you are right. He mentioned at the starting, that he wants to `generate a random string in the starting of the email`.

Answer (score 1):

```
(1..8).map{|i| ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)]}.join
```

8 is the number of characters you want to generate randomly.

Answer (score -1):

create an action in your application controller like this :

```
private 
  def generate_random_string
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)
  end
```

And use it like this in any controller you want:

```
def update
  @user = User.find_by_id(4)
  @user.email = generate_random_string + @user.email
end
```

Comment: Adding this method to `before_update` will prepend to the current email_adress on each update. Resulting in `foo1_foo2_foo3_dipak@gmail.com`. I doubt this is useful or required. You should use `before_create` instead.

Comment: `before_action` is a method for controllers, it has nothing to do with models

Comment: Yes it will, But I thought they need same functionality.

Comment: @YuryLebedev, the answer states: "before_update *in your model*"

Comment: Thanks @TheCha͢mp fixed typo.

Comment: what if i want a method in the application_helper and create a method there and use it in the controller , this is because i am using this method in different model as well

Comment: You need to add it in every model, If you want to save it in db. Where you want to do this ?

Comment: Yes @TheCha͢mp It will add on each update. and question is for same.

Comment: @Dipak in the controller i want to call the method and pass the email as the arguement

Comment: Yes, the question states that, but I assume he did not think of that behavior... you should correct thinking errors as well, or assure he really wants this useless functionality.

Comment: So you can add action in application controller and then call that action in any controller where you want. Updating answer

Answer (score -1):

I hope this will help you.

```
def update
  @user = User.find_by_id(4)
  @user.email = "#{generate_random_string(8)}_#{@user.email}"
  ## You can pass any length to generate_random_string method, in this I have passed 8.
end

private

def generate_random_string(length)
  options = { :length => length.to_i, :chars => ('a'..'z').to_a + ('A'..'Z').to_a + ('0'..'9').to_a }
  Array.new(options[:length]) { options[:chars].to_a[rand(options[:chars].to_a.size)] }.join
end
```

Comment: how does this add to the existing answers in any way?