# Define minimum and maximum length

Tags: ruby, rspec, faker

How is possible to define a minimum and maximum length of user login generated by

```
FFaker::InternetSE.login_user_name
```

Used gem `FFaker`

Comment: It's pure Ruby. Are you using fixtures or factories?

Comment: I'am using factories

Comment: Hitting in the dark. Try `FFaker::InternetSE.login_user_name(8..20)`. Min length: 8 and Max length: 20.

Comment: You can try `FFaker::InternetSE.login_user_name[minimum_length, maximum_length]`. If you need it more than once, you can use a transient.

Comment: @JagdeepSingh `FFaker::InternetSE.login_user_name(8..20)` 
`ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`

Comment: @SebastianPalma
`FFaker::InternetSE.login_user_name[8, 20]` => `""`
 
`FFaker::InternetSE.login_user_name[8, 20]` => "dstrm"

Comment: That's it, you can start from the index zero if you want to "truncate" your string.

Comment: @SebastianPalma

Well yes, but when it generates a string with length 2 and I need minimum to be 8, then there is nothing to truncate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specifying minimum length when using FFaker::Internet.user\_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071115/specifying-minimum-length-when-using-ffakerinternet-user-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the result of `FFaker::InternetSE.login_user_name` and check if the size of the string generated is between the minimum and maximum length you need, if so, return it, otherwise call the function again:

```
require 'ffaker'

def login_user_name(min, max)
  raise 'max can not be minor than min' if min > max
  username = FFaker::InternetSE.login_user_name
  username.size.between?(min, max) ? username : login_user_name(min, max)
end

p login_user_name(8, 9) # christian
p login_user_name(9, 8) # `login_user_name': max can not be minor than min (RuntimeError)
```